# Keyboard Automatic typing

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard, imac

So I have a script that I use in Apple ScriptEditor that automatically types the letters I add and types it when I run the script. But the problem that occurs is that it types all letters individually and I require some letters to be pressed at the same time.

Example if I want to type the letters:

1. A B C [DUE] [FGH]

I want to make modifications to this script so that the letters in " [] " are pressed/typed at once. While the individual letters are pressed/typed individually. Let me know what could be added to change this.

Here is the script:

```
tell application "Roblox" to activate
tell application "System Events"
repeat with i from 1 to count characters of texttowrite
keystroke (character i of texttowrite)
delay 0.08
end repeat
end tell*
```